# Can I dynamically expose an entire SCSI host over Fibre Channel, preferably in Linux

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, scsi, fibre-channel

Is it possible to expose an entire SCSI host dynamically (an LSI HBA or RAID card) over Fibre Channel, if so how?

Preferably on Linux (perhaps targetcli) and with disk hotplugging support. (i.e. unplug/replug a disk in the target and the initiator sees the change)

My FC HBAs are two QLogic QLA2462 cards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can do that. Good summary is here:

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/fedora-diy-fc-san/122877

Some good play with SCST instead of a default LIO is here (uses QLogic HBAs):

http://scst.sourceforge.net/qla2x00t-howto.html

In a nutshell: You can expose any physical or virtual block device as FC target.

Comment: I know about this, but can you pass the **entire** HBA through?

Comment: HBA can operate either in initiator or in target mode, so if you reprogram it into required target mode you lose all initiator functionality so can’t use attached FC devices for anything.

Comment: As in expose every device of another HBA (e.g a SAS hba), automatically over FC